# calling models method from views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to call a method defined in my models.py from my views, but I'm getting this message:

```
unbound method add_question_history() must be called with QuestionHistory instance as first argument (got User instance instead)
```

This is my model:

```
class QuestionHistory(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.question)

def add_question_history(user, question):
    qs = self.create(
        question = question,
        user = user
    )
    self.save()
```

And this how I'm trying to call this method in the view:

```
QuestionHistory.add_question_history(request.user, question_ID)
```

Comment: You're trying to call a model method on the class itself, which doesn't work -- a model method can only be called on an INSTANCE of the class, ie on an single QuestionHistory object.  I'm also unclear of what you're trying to do with this method that wouldn't be solved but just doing `QuestionHistory(question=question, user=request.user).save()` -- the model method itself seems redundant, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: you're right, the method is redundant. I will try your way creating the new row from the view directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to invoke  an **instance method** without an instance.

It seems to be that what you want it's a **classmethod**

So for your code to work you have either make an instance first or create `add_question_history` as a **classmethod**.

Making an instance:

```
class QuestionHistory(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.question)

   def add_question_history(self, user, question):
       qs = self.objects.create(
               question = question,
               user = user
       )
      qs.save()
      #more stuff

 QuestionHistory().add_question_history(request.user, questionID)
```

Making a classmethod:

```
class QuestionHistory(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.question)

       @classmethod
       def add_question_history(cls, user, question):
           qs = cls.objects.create(
                   question = question,
                   user = user
           )
        qs.save()
        #stuff

 QuestionHistory.add_question_history(user,question)
```

For better understanding read [this](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods)